# Front audio jack not working on 22.04?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

I have recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my machine which has a Gigabye H310M-H motherboard. I normally only listen to audio on my computer through headphones, which I plug in the front panel jack, but when I do so, sound doesn't work, and the only output that appears in the sound settings is "Dummy Output". It doesn't happen when I plug speakers on the back panel of the computer, with which sound works perfectly, so I know it's not a driver issue. I remember I had the exact same issue on Windows back then, which was solved by tweaking the Realtek audio GUI console. Did anyone have the same problem? Do you know how to fix it? Thanks right away.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Ubuntu 22.04, i7 13th gen, Nvidia GeForce RTX3080. Rear AUX jack works normally, but no audio from from front AUX jack. Headphones are correctly detected by the system but no sound from it. I am investigating about this issue.